# Add a newline to a string in Scilab

Tags: scilab

Create a simple string in Scilab containing a newline.

Seems simple enough, but Scilab only seems to interpret escape sequences through printf style functions and `msprintf` / `sprintf` splits the string into a vector of strings at the newline!

The only way I can see to achieve this is to actually write a newline out to a file and read it back in again. Surely there is a simpler way to do this!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, found it. The `ascii` function will do the job, a newline can be added via its ascii decimal -

```
str = 'hello' + ascii(10) + 'world'
```